# Amazon SES Gmail spaming issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, gmail, spam-prevention, amazon-ses, sendy

I am using Amazon SES for bulk email, for some reasons my email in Gmail going into spam, on hotmail, yahoo, aol etc are working fine. i have fully setup SPF & DKIM here are the stats from mail-tester https://www.mail-tester.com/web-O1hxHT and my score is 7.9/10

i will be thankful any expert can help me what should i do so Gmail also accept my email into inbox rather than spam.

for email i am using Sendy

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check the report of the mail-tester in the blacklist area. Your ip is listed on two blacklists (CASA-CBLPLUS, SORBS-SPAM). Delist your ip on the blacklist. If you have a shared ip, change to a dedicated. The email providers use different blacklists. Google always has a tool for postmaster (https://gmail.com/postmaster/) you can register your domain and check the reputation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I configure google postmaster as well to fetch the issue why my email is going into spam i added enteries in DNS to verify my domain on google but for some reasons it is not showing up any results there too.

Comment: This site is about **programming** problems - not about spam policies of a service provider. It is no surprise that the answers you got are nothing but rants. I think your question seriously does not fit the policies of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Amazon SES email's should not end up in junk, no matter the service provider. Have you used the same account for sometime? Maybe check if the domain has been marked as spam

Ive used this site in the past: https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the IP address you are using is blacklisted:

http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

If it is, you'll need to contact Amazon to get it removed.

(Amazon SES seems to have a very lax policy towards spam. I just got spammed for a third time from a spammer who scraped an address from google play. I've reported them twice before, but each time Amazon just sends a stock email saying "We are sorry to hear that you received unwanted email through Amazon SES..." and nothing ever happens. If you look at the Amazon SES forums, you'll see that blacklisting of their IP addresses is a continual problem).

Comment: I think this is nothing but a *rant*. It would be ok as comment, but what is it **answering**?

Comment: It's not a rant, as it is based on facts...both of my experience and the fact that they constantly get blacklisted. The only solution is to get Amazon to properly deal with spam.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not an answer in the scope of this community.